# How to parse datetime and time from strings and how to add these parsed datetime and time values in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time, timedelta

I am parsing datetime objects from strings, 
In these situation I faced a problem where I have to add datetime object with time object together to create combined timestamp.

I know there is a datetime.combine method but unfortunately I could not use it in this situation

e.g. there are two strings, one contains formatted datetime and other has formatted time like below

```
dt_str = "2018/11/27 14:12:32"
tm_str = "1:23:45.678" # 1 hour 23 minutes 11 seconds and 750 micro seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dt_str = "2018/11/27 14:12:32"
tm_str = "1:23:45.678"
```

First we need to import from python's standard libraries i.e. datetime, time and timedelta

```
import datetime, time
from datetime import timedelta
```

Then we will parse dt_str as datetime object and tm_str as time object

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
tm = time.strptime(tm_str, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Now we will use timedelta class to add hours, minutes and seconds to the datetime object from time object

```
timestamp = dt + timedelta(hours=tm.tm_hour) + \
timedelta(minutes=tm.tm_min) + timedelta(seconds=tm.tm_sec)
```

Results

```
print("dt:", dt)
print("tm:", tm)
print("timestamp: ", timestamp)
```

Note: You can not add microseconds value, at least I do not know the method. If someone knows better way to do above operations please put your solutions below

```
dt: 2018-11-27 14:12:32
tm: time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=1, tm_min=23, tm_sec=45, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
timestamp: 2018-11-27 15:36:17
```

Comment: You can still create accurate timedelta objects using date arithmetics. This will work as long as tm_str fits the format pattern (i.e. <= 1 day): `from datetime import datetime as dt; dt.strptime(dt_str, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") + (dt.strptime(tm_str, "%H:%M:%S.%f") - dt.min.replace(year=1900))`. It does keep the microseconds: `2018-11-27 15:36:17.678000`